# Сравнение значений в массиве Js и выбор наименьшего

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив :

```
{
"id": 1422,
"status": "Completed",
"customer": {
    "id": 1235,
    "name": "Государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение города Москва \"Гимназия №4\"",
    "address": "г. Москва, ул. Строителей, д. 12, офис 6",
    "email": "info@acme.ru",
    "phone": "408-867-5309"
},
"condition": {
    "nameTRY": "Молоко питьевое пастеризованное, м.д жира 2.5%",
    "requirments": "ГОСТ 10705-80",
    "ordertype": "Закупка до 100 000 руб.  (п. 4 ст.93 Закона №44-ФЗ)",
    "ordersize": 100,
    "maxdate": "22.08.2018",
    "orderplan": "Опишите график поставки",
    "orderplace": 102,
    "pickupinstore": true,
    "pickupinstoredescription": "поле для ввода информации о возможном месте самовывоза заказчиком",
    "startprice": 1000,
    "oneprice": 10.98,
    "startfinalprice": 1000,
    "payterms": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию.",
    "licenseneeded": true,
    "additionaInfo": "Текстовое поле, вводится заказчиком, пустое по умолчанию."
},
"offers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 1000,
        "organizations": [
            {
                "id": 1000,
                "name": "Победитель",
                "email": "pop@pop.pop"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 1000,
        "organizations": [
            {
                "id": 1001,
                "name": "Наименование организации",
                "email": "pop@pop.ru"
            },
            {
                "id": 1002,
                "name": "Наименование организации",
                "email": "pop@pop.com"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"files": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Наименование документа",
        "filename": "table.pdf"
    }
],
"organizationFinal": {
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Наименование организации",
    "email": "org@org.ru"
},
"proposals": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 700,
        "organizationid": 1001,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:52.184375"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 800,
        "organizationid": 1000,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:38.034244"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 900,
        "organizationid": 1002,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:23.222149"
    }
]
}
```

В данном массиве необходимо сравнить значения из раздела `proposals`, выбрать один с наименьшим значением `price` (либо выбрать значение с наименьшим `id`, если минимальный `price` совпадает) и сравнить значение `organizationid` с значением `id` из массива `organizationFinal`.
Только начал изучать JS, понимаю что это делается через циклы, но пока что не могу понять как это реализовать.

Comment: В чём проблемы?

Comment: Ну допустим, я понимаю примерно, как найти и выбрать минимальное значение из необходимых. Но я совсем пока что не понимаю как потом мне определить из какого массива оно было взято что бы сравнить с нужным значением.

Comment: Покажите что Вы понимаете.

Comment: @Other В ответах указал - можете посмотреть и возможно что-то поправить посоветовать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким способом. Работаю в Postman - штуки типа `pm.environment.set` оттуда (price в массиве не может быть больше 100000 :

```
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody) ;
pm.environment.set("prop", jsonData.proposals.length -1 );
var price = 1000000;
if (pm.environment.get("prop") == -1 ) {
    console.log (jsonData.status);
} else {
 for (var i = 0;i <= pm.environment.get("prop"); i++ )  { 
     if  (price > jsonData.proposals[pm.environment.get("prop")].price ) 
     {
    var price = jsonData.proposals[pm.environment.get("prop")].price;   
    var id = jsonData.proposals[pm.environment.get("prop")].organizationid;
     }
          pm.environment.set("prop", (pm.environment.get("prop") -1))  ;
   }
   console.log (id == jsonData.organizationFinal.id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Через циклы [больше не нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/):

```
let arr_min = Math.min.apply( ...arr );
```

Comment: А как это применить к массиву объектов, как у автора вопроса?

Comment: хм, или просто через циклы и сохранять имя массива текущего минимального значения в отдельной переменной?

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта, первый со сложностью `O(n)`, второй немного сложнее (`O(n*log(n)`), но на мой взгляд, выглядит изящнее:

```js
let data = { // убрал несущественные для вопроса поля объекта
"organizationFinal": {
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "Наименование организации",
    "email": "org@org.ru"
},
"proposals": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 700,
        "organizationid": 1001,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:52.184375"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 800,
        "organizationid": 1000,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:38.034244"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "features": "Заполняется автоматически, выводится перечень характеристик, установленные для заполнения поставщиком в оферте шаблоном позиции. Могут варьироваться в зависимости от типа товара, работ, услуг.",
        "code": "o124",
        "name": "Наименование ТРУ",
        "additionalFeatures": "Дополнительные характеристики, которые могут задаваться поставщиком при вводе информации об оферте, выбранной заказчиком при формировании заказа на закупку",
        "price": 900,
        "organizationid": 1002,
        "orderid": 1422,
        "createdat": "2018-05-29T13:02:23.222149"
    }
]};

function checkFinal1 (obj) { // Вариант 1
  let min = {}; // тут будем хранить данные о минимальном элементе
  obj.proposals.forEach(item => {
    if (!min.price // при первой итерации min.price будет undefined
      || (item.price < min.price || (item.price == min.price && item.id < min.id))) { // если очередной элемент меньше минимума, сохраняем его как минимальный
      min.price = item.price;
      min.id = item.id;
      min.orgId = item.organizationid;
    }
  });

  return min.orgId == obj.organizationFinal.id;
}

function checkFinal2 (obj) { // Вариант 2
  let min = [].concat(obj.proposals) // создаем новый массив из obj.proposals; 
                                     // если изменение порядка элементов proposals в исходном объекте допустимо, 
                                     // тогда этот шаг можно пропустить.
    .sort((a, b) => { // сортируем
      let priceDiff = a.price - b.price;
      return priceDiff ? priceDiff : a.id - b.id;
  })[0] // и берем первый элемент, он и будет минимальным

  return min.organizationid == obj.organizationFinal.id;
}

console.log(checkFinal1(data));
console.log(checkFinal2(data));
```